# PHP echo statement within getElementByID div tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo, getelementbyid

I've currently got a form which i use from Gravity forms, here is my html code

```
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">SPECIFY PRODUCT</button>
    <div id="myDropdown_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="dropdown-content">
    <?php gravity_form( 1, false, false, false, '', true ); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

as you can see i'm echoing the product ID from woocommerce to give a different  div id dependent on which product the user clicks on. This works fine.

Although, now when i create javascript function :

```
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>").classList.toggle("show");
    }
```

how can I pull through 'get_the_ID' like i have in the html code so it can dropdown my form in accordance to the product selected?

You can take a look at it here : http://www.ctagroup.com.au/cta-group-home/products/tactile-guidance/suresteel/suresteel-classic/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Did you get an error?

Comment: whta's yoyr problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is because the `"myDropdown_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"` part is [treated as string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLUEV.png) not PHP code.

Try this way:

```
<script>
    var theId = "<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>";

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown_" + theId).classList.toggle("show");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried putting this in my script @Risan although still the buttons do not dropdown. I'm getting these errors -

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating     'document.getElementById("myDropdown_" + theId).classList')
myFunctionsuresteel-classic:483
onclicksuresteel-classic:787

Comment: With Gravity Forms I have followed these steps [link] https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_enqueue_scripts/

in my functions.php file

`add_action( 'gform_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_script', 10, 2 );`  

in my header.php

`<?php 
add_action( 'gform_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_script', 10, 2 );  
function enqueue_custom_script( $1, true ) {  
    if ( true ) {  
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_script', 'path/file.js' );  
    }  
}  
?>`

Comment: it seems that the variable is pulling through the id although where is it pulling it from? It does not match any of the product ID's.  The variable needs to pull through the ID from the product that is selected although i'm unsure of how to do that. http://i.imgur.com/K2oB2fD.png?1

Answer (score 0):

You always can try to generate JS code by PHP instead. 
Of course in case, if the attempts to solve the problem have been unsuccessful.
Don't see any problems with this "technique".